# How do I assign foreign keys to a MySQL table from a csv file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I am trying to set up a database for the first time using MySQL Workbench. I have 3 csv files: `parent.csv`, `child.csv`, `parent_to_child.csv`. The `parent.csv` and `child.csv` files simply contain 1 column with many rows (50,000+) of unique string identifiers (alphanumeric).

parent.csv

```
parent_id
parent001
parent002
parent003
parent004
...
```

child.csv

```
child_id
child001
child002
child003
child004
...
```

So far, I managed to create `parent` and `child` tables with a surrogate auto-increment primary key (integer).

`parent` table

```
id_num parent_id
1      parent001
2      parent002
3      parent003
4      parent004
...    ...
```

`child` table

```
id_num child_id
1      child001
2      child002
3      child003
4      child004
5      child005
...    ...
```

I would now like to have each `child` in the table to reference its `parent`. The `child` to `parent` mappings are stored in `parent_to_child.csv`.

parent_to_child.csv

```
parent_id, child_id
parent001, child004
parent001, child003
parent002, child005
parent003, child001
parent003, child002
...      , ...
```

so the desired result would be something like:

`child` table where `id_num_parent` is a foreign key referencing the `parent` table

```
id_num child_id id_num_parent
1      child001 2
2      child002 3
3      child003 1
4      child004 1
5      child005 2
...    ...      ...
```

So my approach was to alter the `child` table to include a new `id_num_parent` which would be a foreign key column referencing the `parent` table. Then, I can use `parent_to_child.csv` to assign the foreign keys to each `child_id`.

This is my attempt that fails:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'parent_to_child.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE child
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1, @col2) set child_id=@col2, id_num_parent=@col1;
```

This returns an `Incorrect integer value` since `@col1` is the `parent_id` (string), not the `id_num` (int) of the parent.

So I believe my main problem is figuring out how to get `id_num` from `parent_id` in the `parent` table and then assigning `id_num` to `id_num_parent` for `child_id` in the `child` table.

Comment: Do you actually need to create numeric id? You could just use the child_id and parent_id as primary identifier.

Comment: My understanding is that using a string as a primary key is not good for performance. Also, my understanding is that it's better to have your primary key as a surrogate one over a 'business' one. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct actually.

Comment: Why do you have parents and children instead of just people? With parent-child telling you which people are related as parent & child.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean to have this structure of two entity types and a many-to-many association: After you get parent and child tables with autoincrement ids, read parent_child into the database temporarily, join all three on child_ids and parent_ids, then select child id_num, child_id & id_num_parent into a permanent table.

Answer (score 0):

You should only remove extra characters in column data like 'parent' & 'child' as that already distinguished by separate tables.

So create an update query to remove those characters and retain numeric values only. Then change column data type to `int`

Query like:

```
Update parent set parent_id = substr(parent_id,9,1)
```

Comment: What if the alphabetical characters are significant to the uniqueness of each record? The actual strings representing parent001, parent002, and parent003 don't share the same prefixes like 'parent' (think of them as unique usernames). I apologize for the original example being misleading.

Comment: In that case primary key of string is not an issue

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding when to use 'surrogate' keys. If I use a primary key of string in this case, and if a parent id like parent001 gets changed to parent0001, wouldn't that require me to change all foreign key values from parent001 to parent0001?

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is a special constraint on a column or set of columns. A primary key constraint ensures that the column(s) so designated have no NULL values, and that every value is unique. Physically, a primary key is implemented by the database system using a unique index, and all the columns in the primary key must have been declared NOT NULL. A table may have only one primary key, but it may be composite (consist of more than one column).

A surrogate key is any column or set of columns that can be declared as the primary key instead of a "real" or natural key. Sometimes there can be several natural keys that could be declared as the primary key, and these are all called candidate keys. So a surrogate is a candidate key. A table could actually have more than one surrogate key, although this would be unusual. The most common type of surrogate key is an incrementing integer, such as an auto_increment column in MySQL, or a sequence in Oracle, or an identity column in SQL Server.

So you have two options:

1. Create surrogate key with auto_increment Or
2. Create surrogate key with parent and child ids

**Then create reference of these fields with parent_to_child table.**